# Ruby on Rails : create array from activerecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a query to find properties by a certain criteria. I'm including the Users table in the query so I can have access to the property owner (user_id) and send them an email about the property.

```
@testproperties.users.each do |property|
  UserMailer.with(property: property, user: property.user).check_listing.deliver
  property.update_columns(property_reminder_date: Time.now )
end
```

This works fine, except since I'm looping through properties, if a user has more than 1 property, they will receive X amount of emails. I want to bundle this by users.

So if a user has 2 properties, I want to send the mailer the user and their multiple properties. they will receive 1 email instead of two. and the email view will be fed an array of properties.

But I'm not sure how to do this. I need to loop over users and have their properties connected to them.

Edit:

if I do a query like:

```
      @testusers = User.joins(:properties)
      .where("properties.updated_at < :date", date: 30.days.ago)
      .where("properties.property_reminder_date < :date OR properties.property_reminder_date IS NULL", date: 30.days.ago)
      .where('properties.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(property_id) FROM transactions)')
```

This will give me the users I need to email to, however, accessing each user's properties shows ALL properties rather than the ones I need based on my SQL queries.

Edit again:

I was able to achieve what I wanted in a really messy way:

```
      @testusers = User.joins(:properties)
      .where("properties.updated_at < :date", date: 30.days.ago)
      .where("properties.property_reminder_date < :date OR properties.property_reminder_date IS NULL", date: 30.days.ago)
      .where('properties.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(property_id) FROM transactions)')
      @testusers = @testusers.uniq

      @testusers.each do |user|
        propertyList = user.properties.active.has_not_updated
        UserMailer.with(properties: propertyList, user: user).check_listing.deliver
        propertyList.each do |property|
          property.update_columns(property_reminder_date: Time.now )
        end
      end
```

Property model:

```
...
   scope :active, -> { where('expires_at >= ?', Time.now) }
  scope :has_not_updated, -> {active.where("updated_at < :date", date: 30.days.ago).where("property_reminder_date < :date OR property_reminder_date IS NULL", date: 30.days.ago).where('id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(property_id) FROM transactions)') }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
properties.group_by(&:user).each do |user,  properties|
  UserMailer.send_email(user, properties).deliver_later
end
```

In each iteration you will have user and array of user's properties.

Comment: thank you. that's much cleaner than what I came up with. I realize I forgot to include some code in my question. resulted in downvotes.